# Open URL in already-opened Firefox profile

Tags: macos, firefox, command-line

I've got a couple Firefox profiles constantly open on my Mac (I'm running Snow Leopard), and I'd like a command that will open a new tab in one of them. I've been trying variations on this:

> firefox -P targetProfileName -remote "openurl(http://example.com, new-tab)"

but it keeps complaining that "A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time." I know it's already open; I want the new tab in the window that's already there. Any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Try `open -a Firefox 'http://example.com/'`. This opens the given URL with Firefox, starting it if it doesn't already run.

If you skip the `-a Firefox` part, then the URL will be opened with the default browser.

Comment: Thank you!! This helped me today and will help me in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have Mozilla Firefox already open with the Default profile or anyother profile, try:

```
Path-To/firefox -remote openurl("http://www.example.org")
```

Tested and worked for me with Mozilla Firefox from 2.x to 12.x

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how remoting works on the Mac as I don't have one, but on Windows and Linux you can only have one profile enabled for remoting at once; you need to start that profile normally, and and all the other profiles with `-no-remote`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours designing my webpage with firefox 17.0+.

Since the profile page is already open, you wound't need the -remote option.

I was trying it as `firefox -P webpage -no-remote 'openurl(%p)'`

Where %p was argument.

What worked for me was to open in an existing opened profile was:

firefox -P webpage -new-tab '%p%

Answer (score 0):

In 2020-01-23, this method works (assuming the profile is already open, I did not test with a closed profile).

**firefox -P NAME_might_need_to_quote -new_tab URL_might_need_to_quote**

Almost a decade later, I'm switching browsers to Firefox and was wondering exactly the same thing.

E.G.

firefox -P NONdefault -new_tab "https://example.com/"